# Using a Swift Timer in a MacOS command-line-tool / daemon which uses Swift-NIO for networking: RunLoop vs wait issue

Tags: swift, macos, swift-nio

I'm converting a Swift MacOS command-line tool/daemon to use Swift-NIO for networking.  This is my first Swift-NIO project.

The tool fires a timer every 0.1 second.  Here's the line at the bottom of main.swift which fires up the daemon/runloop, prior to the Swift-NIO conversion:

```
RunLoop.current.run()
```

Here's the timer in my Universe.swift class init().  There is always exactly one instance of this class:

```
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0 / updatesPerSecond, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer?.tolerance = 0.3 / updatesPerSecond
    debugPrint("Timer initialized")
    if let timer = timer {
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    }
```

In this configuration the timer fires 10 times per second as expected.  But if I get any network input my Swift-NIO library crashes because its not in the expected event loop.

[image]
In Swift-NIO, I'm supposed to add a channel.closeFuture.wait() line to the bottom of my main.swift:

```
// This will never unblock as we don't close the ServerChannel.
try channel.closeFuture.wait()
RunLoop.current.run()
```

That solves the Swift-NIO crash, but then I never get to my timer RunLoop, so my timer doesn't fire.

How can I use Swift-NIO to receive (and send) network data, while still having a timer running?

If it helps, the full open source for this project is at https://github.com/darrellroot/netrek-server-swift.

Comment: The SwiftNIO crash you saw is missing some context. Can you provide the code that you’re using in response to the timer firing (the `timerFired` selector)? This is likely violating a threading requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasa was right.  I was missing (and not understanding) some important context.

My timer was eventually trying to send data using SwiftNIO like so:

```
    if let context = context {
        let buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(bytes: data)
        _ = context.channel.writeAndFlush(buffer)
    }
```

The fix was to "dispatch" the sending of the traffic to the context-related EventLoop:

```
    if let context = context {
        context.eventLoop.execute {
                let buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(bytes: data)
                _ = context.channel.writeAndFlush(buffer)
        }
    }
```

It feels very similar to DispatchQueue.main.async { } for updating the GUI in iOS apps, but with different Swift-NIO related terminology.